# Creating shapes in similar fashion as with autoshape dropdown

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to make a macro in Powerpoint that enables me to create shapes in a similar fashion as when you select the autoshapes in the autoshape overview (i.e. once you call the macro you have a possibility to click to set the coordinates and subsequently you drag and click to set the width&height). Also, I would like to give it pre-set cosmetic characteristics (e.g. certain inner margins, fill color, border style and transparancy), which will be defined in the vba code.

I am aware of .addshapes(), however, this requires coordinates and height/width as input. Moreover, I have not find any posts / documents on vba to create shapes without defined coordinates and height/width.
Anyone some ideas on how to tackle this challenge?

Many thanks in advance!

Sofar

Answer (score 1):

Building on what John Korchok suggested, here's code that retrieves the just-drawn shape so that your code can resume and manipulate it...

```
Sub testAppComBars()
    Dim SHP As Shape

    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ShapeFreeform")

    Stop

    Set SHP = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    With SHP.Fill
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0.75
    End With
End Sub
```

I would hope there's a more elegant solution than using `Stop` to pause code execution while the user picks the shape's location (or in this case, draws a freeform polyline/polygon), but that's all I could come up with off the top of my head.

Comment: Hmm it seems to result in an compile error 'variable not defined' (w.r.t. 'selection'). Hence, the code does not run.

Comment: I encountered the same thing when I first tried it in Excel, and the issue was me mouse-clicking off the just-drawn shape causing it to become unselected prior to resuming the stopped subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

I was fascinated by this problem and think this might help you.

Consider that when you draw a new autoshape, you have changed the window selection, and created a new selection ShapeRange with exactly 1 item (the new shape).

So by setting a WindowSelectionChange event, you're able to apply any formatting you wish at the time of creation.

First create a class module called cPptEvents with the following:

```
Public WithEvents PPTEvent As Application

Private Sub PPTEvent_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal sel As Selection)
    On Error GoTo Errhandler
    Debug.Print "IN_PPTEvent_WindowSelectionChange"

    Dim oShp As Shape

    If (ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal) Then
        With sel
            If .Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
                If .ShapeRange.Count = 1 Then
                    Set oShp = .ShapeRange(1)
                    If oShp.Type = msoAutoShape Then
                        If oShp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval Then
                           If oShp.Tags("new_oval") = "" Then
                                oShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                                oShp.Tags.Add "new_oval", "true"
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With

    End If



    Exit Sub

Errhandler:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

This checks the selection every time it changes.  If there's an oval selected, it looks for the "new_oval" tag, which will not exist for a newly created shape.  In that case, it applies a red fill, although of course once you get to this point you can call an entirely different sub, pass along the shape, and do whatever you want formatting-wise to it.

By adding that "new_oval" tag, you ensure that the formatting will not be applied to an oval that hasn't been newly created. This allows the user to make manual changes to the formatting as needed -- otherwise you're just resetting the formatting every time the user selects an oval.

Note that for the _WindowSelectionChange event to be running in the background, you have to call this at some point:

```
Public MyEventClassModule As New cPptEvents

'
Public Sub StartMeUp()
   Set MyEventClassModule.PPTEvent = Application
End Sub
```

You can include that one line from StartMeUp above in whatever Ribbon_Onload sub is triggered by your addin, if you're making a new addin ribbon.

With this solution, you don't even have to give the end user a special button or set of tools to create the shapes that are being formatted. It happens invisibly whenever the user draws a new shape from the native PPT tools.

Answer (score 0):

This will put your cursor in drawing mode to draw an oval. After running, you may have to click on the slide once, then the cursor will change shape and you can draw an oval:

```
Sub DrawOval()
  Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ShapeOval")
End Sub
```

Other commands to substitute for ShapeOval:
ShapeRectangle
ShapeElbowConnectorArrow
ShapeStraightConnectorArrow
Get the full list in Excel spreadsheets from Microsoft [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745)
Look for the powerpointcontrols.xlsx file and search the first column with "shape"

There are 173 shapes in the menu, so you have a lot of macros to write.

Comment: That's some cool vba code, thank you. However, it seems that I cannot pre-format this to be drawn shape (e.g. a different color and font size than the default shapestyle) as .executemso does not allow for additional arguments (like .fill). Of course it can be formatted afterwards, but that is not ideal. Hence would you have a suggestion on how to pre-format the shape?

Comment: Sorry, it's all or nothing for presetting formatting. You can preformat the object including position and size, or you can draw the object using this workaround and apply formatting later. A workaround to the workaround would be to set your desired formatting as the shape default before running the command. Here is Microsoft's help page on the SetShapesDefaultProperties command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.setshapesdefaultproperties